# Understanding generic method return types

Tags: java, jpa, generics

In the `public interface Path<X> extends Expression<X>`  there has one method which is:

```
<Y> Path<Y> get(String attributeName);
```

I don't understand how this generic method works. In the parameter list, there has no define the generic but how to confirm the return type?

I do my experiment like:

```
class abc<Y> implements myinterfa<Y> {
    Y ab;

    public <Y> Y get(String attributeName) {
        return ab;
    }
}
```

It is not working on compile time.

The error message is:

> Incompatible types.
>   Required:
>   Y
>   Found:
>   Y

PS------------

```
  @Override
    public List<WebSite> list(WebSite webSite, Integer page, Integer pageSize) {
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, pageSize, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");
        Page<WebSite> pageWebSite = webSiteRepository.findAll(new Specification<WebSite>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<WebSite> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
                if (webSite != null) {
                    if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(webSite.getName())) {
                        predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.like(root.get("name"), "%" + webSite.getName().trim() + "%"));
                    }
                    if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(webSite.getUrl())) {
                        predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.like(root.get("url"), "%" + webSite.getUrl().trim() + "%"));
                    }
                }
                return predicate;
            }
        }, pageable);
        return pageWebSite.getContent();
    }
```

this method is in my BLL, my repository is:

```
public interface WebSiteRepository extends JpaRepository<WebSite, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<WebSite> {

}
```

and I follow the invoke chain to the Path interface:

```
public interface Path<X> extends Expression<X> {
    <Y> Path<Y> get(String attributeName);
}
```

the generic method has been called, but I do not know how this method working.

PS2----------

let me to clear the question:

How the get method of the interface Path confirms the Y identifier? the interface and the method are not using the same Identifier.I can not use 
`Path<String> path = new subClass<String>()` 
to confirm the parameter type.
And in the parameter signature there is no to define the generic parameter type like:

```
<Y> Path<Y> get(Y attributeName);
```

In this format, I can call the method with:

```
String result = path.get("vincent");
```

because when I pass the "vincent" to this method, The identifier Y is confirmed.

the get method is making me confuse to use generic, I do not know how to make this method working or return something useful.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is `Path`. How are you calling `get`

Comment: use `abc` instead of `abc<Y>`

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring the class as generic **and** the method as generic, but both are using `Y` as an identifier for the type parameter. You need to remove the `<Y>` from the `get` method and everything will be fine:

```
class abc<Y> implements myinterfa<Y> {
    Y ab;

    public Y get(String attributeName) {
        return ab;
    }
}
```

The `get` method could be made generic independently from the class (though in your case - and indeed most cases - it does not make sense) but you would need to choose a different identifier:

```
class abc<Y> implements myinterfa<Y> {
    public <T> T get(String attributeName) {
        return null; /* or something useful... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Or from the class declaration ... ?

Comment: @YassinHajaj You can't because `Y` is also used in `implements myinterfa<Y>`

Comment: You should probably note that this signature: `static <E> Path<E> methodName() { }` should usually be used statically. If it is a member of a class, you drop the `static <E>` and make sure the generic symbol matches the one in the class definition e.g. `Path<T> methodName() { }` where `ClassName<T>`.

Comment: @Michael I mean from the `abc<Y>` part. We could just do something like this normally `class abc implements myinterfa<Y>`

Comment: @YassinHajaj You can't do that. Feel free to try it, but it will not compile.

Comment: @YassinHajaj The generic type symbol for the interface must exist and be defined for the class first. You will get a `symbol Y does not exist` compilation error.

Comment: I am using the JPA with spring data, my Repository is implementing the JpaSpecificationExecutor, when I use the findAll method that JpaSpecificationExecutor subclass provides it gives me the Root<Y> root parameter. the root parameter can call the get method which is I mention in the question. I do not know how this method working, the generic method can not be defined the actually type when I call it.

Comment: @Michael I just confused this with a non-generic implementation. Actually we could do something like this `class abc implements myinterfa<String>`

Comment: @YassinHajaj That removes the generic ability from the class, you are just implementing a String interface at that point. `Y` is a symbol for representing the type of the class.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Indeed but this was the whole point of the confusion. But you could be needing a non-generic implementation of your interface, with generic methods becoming non-generic methods.